# Javascript "includes" splitting items in array by dash (VueJS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building an App using VueJS and Laravel.

**TLDR;**

*includes* function in VueJS is not giving the same output as it does in Javascript. It is splitting values within an array by the dash. Is there a way to prevent this?

**Set up**

I have a JSON with a list of languages, including their key and value. For example:

```
{"en":"English","en-au":"English (Australia)"}
```

I import this list and then push it into the `data` as the value `languages`

Then in order to separate the list of languages that are already selected, I have a hidden input that has an array of these pre-selected languages:

```
<input type="hidden" value="['en-ca', 'pt']" name="used_languages" id="used_languages">
```

Then, just to test, I am putting them through a foreach loop:

```
<li v-for="(value, key) in languages" v-if="used_languages.includes(key)">@{{ value }}</li>
```

**Problem**

However, what is odd is that for this example, the following languages appear on the front end:

- Catalan
- English
- English (Canada)
- Portuguese (Portugal)

Note that I only have Canadian English and Portuguese in the array of values for used_languages.

It looks like *includes* is splitting *en-ca* by the dash and seeing if either *en* or *ca* are in the list and then taking these as well as *en-ca* as a whole.

This is not the expected behaviour.

**Desired Behaviour:**

To check the documentation, it should be like this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

It should only filter out Canadian English and Portuguese.

**Question**

Does anyone know why this is happening and how can I fix it?

All comments and questions are welcome!

Thanks a lot!

## **Answer**

Thanks @SteveArcher for the massive help! To make Steve's point clear in terms of my example, what I had to do was:

- Change my input value, which was kind of an array within a string to be an actual array. Since it was always going to be in the quotes, I decided to make it a comma-separated list and then turn it into an array in JS.

Old:

```
<input type="hidden" value="['en-ca', 'pt']" name="used_languages" id="used_languages">
```

New:

```
<input type="hidden" value="en-ca,pt" name="used_languages" id="used_languages">
```

Notice that there are no spaces in there. That is important.

- Then, as mentioned above, I needed to turn this comma-separated list into an array in JS (within the created function in Vue):

Old:

```
this.used_languages = doc.getElementById('used_languages').value
```

New:

```
this.used_languages = doc.getElementById('used_languages').value.split(',')
```

Thanks again Steve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running `.includes` on the string `"['en-ca', 'pt']"`, not the array `['en-ca', 'pt']` as you're expecting. For a string, includes will match any substring, (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes ), so that's why it's matching `"en"` `"en-ca"` `"ca"` and `"pt"`. Convert that string back into an array before calling `.includes` and you'll be golden!

Comment: You are absolutely right Steve! Thanks so much for pointing this out! I'll add my changes to the answer so that someone can use it if they want. Thanks again! :)